# gather data from .txt and process it using batch

Tags: batch-file, process

```
mango  apple

56.88 97.22

rat cat

bull         dog
```

This is text in `a.txt`. I need a batch script to process each word at a time
i.e reading it and storing it in a variable which requires further processing
eg:

1. mango be set in %var1% and it should be processed next
2. apple in %var2%
3. 56.88 in %var1%.
4. again 97.22 in %var2%...etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Your text is in a text file.  Notepad is just a text editor. Not sure if I am really understanding your problem but here is one attempt at what I think you are trying to do.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN (a.txt) DO (
     FOR %%I IN (%%G) DO ECHO %%I
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should Work

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (a.txt) do (
set var1=%%a
set var2=%%b

echo var1 values is - !var1!
echo var2 values is - !var2!
 )
)
```

Comment: @Vivek GUTHIKONDA, if you found my answer helpful please vote up and if it has solved your problem please accept my answer, it would be easier for other to quickly find answer to similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following stores each item in the text file `a.txt` into variable `ITEM` in two nested loops. The outer one reads the file line per line; the inner one gets the individual items, separated by <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, `,`, `;` or `=`. It also works if there is only one item in a line, or even more than two. Since the variable is changed and read in a code block (loop), expansion (reading) like `%ITEM%` does not work; you will need to enable Delayed Expansion and read the variable like `!ITEM!` then. Type `setlocal /?` and `cmd /?` for more information about that.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq eol=| tokens=*" %%L in ("a.txt") do (
    for %%I in (%%L) do (
        set "ITEM=%%I"
        rem process each ITEM:
        echo Item: !ITEM!
    )
)
endlocal
```

For this approach it is assumed that the items in the text file do not contain any of the following special characters: `?` `*` `%` `!` `/` `\` `:` `(` `)` `&` `^` `|` `<` `>` `"`. If such occur it will fail.